# Change mean indicator in violin plot to a circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, mean, violin-plot

I want to change the the look of the mean in violinplots. I am using matplotlib. I could change the color of the means with the following code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 fig,(axes1,axes2,axes3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=1,figsize=(10,20))

 r=axes2.violinplot(D,showmeans=True,showmedians=True)
 r['cmeans'].set_color('red')
```

But now I want to change the look of the mean (currently a line, like the median) to a 'small circle'.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Perhaps you can post how your current plots look. Also please add some more details to get clear understanding of what exactly is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea can be to obtain the coordinates of the mean lines and plot a scatter plot at those coordinates.

Obtaining the coordinates can

- either be done by looping over the mean lines' paths,

  ```
  # loop over the paths of the mean lines
  xy = [[l.vertices[:,0].mean(),l.vertices[0,1]] for l in r['cmeans'].get_paths()]
  xy = np.array(xy)
  ```
- or by reacalculating the mean from the input data.

  ```
  #alternatively get the means from the data
  y = data.mean(axis=0)
  x = np.arange(1,len(y)+1)
  xy=np.c_[x,y]
  ```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

data = np.random.normal(size=(50, 2))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

r=ax.violinplot(data,showmeans=True)

# loop over the paths of the mean lines
xy = [[l.vertices[:,0].mean(),l.vertices[0,1]] for l in r['cmeans'].get_paths()]
xy = np.array(xy)
##alternatively get the means from the data
#y = data.mean(axis=0)
#x = np.arange(1,len(y)+1)
#xy=np.c_[x,y] 

ax.scatter(xy[:,0], xy[:,1],s=121, c="crimson", marker="o", zorder=3)

# make lines invisible
r['cmeans'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]